# gnuplot's 'steps' style does not accept variable color

Tags: gnuplot

I'm using Gnuplot Version 5.2 patchlevel 6 on Debian 10. The following program

```
$d << EOD
1     0.5   0.1
2     0.75  0.2
3     0.99  0.5
4     1.25  1.1
EOD
plot $d using 1:2:3 w lines lc palette z lw 2
```

produces an expected output:

[image]

But if I change the last line to

```
plot $d using 1:2:3 w steps lc palette z lw 2
```

I receive an error message:

```
line 7: Too many using specs for this style
```

According to paragraphs *II Plotting Styles, Steps* in [Gnuplot User Manual](http://gnuplot.info/docs_5.2/Gnuplot_5.2.pdf)

> The input column requires are the same as for plot styles lines and points.

and in paragraph *II Plotting Styles, Lines* stated that:

> The basic form requires 1, 2, or 3 columns of input data. Additional input columns may be used to provide information such as variable line color

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are drawing `with steps`, the question probably is: which color should the vertical lines have?
Quickly checking the documentation I couldn't find a hint whether variable line color together `with steps` explicitely works or explicitely doesn't work.

In any case, you can workaround with the following code:

**Code:**

```
### plotting with steps and variable line color
reset session

$Data <<EOD
1     0.5   0.1
2     0.75  0.2
3     0.99  0.5
4     1.25  1.1
EOD

set xrange [0:5]
set yrange [0:1.5]

plot x1=y1=NaN $Data u (x0=x1,x1=$1,x0):(y0=y1,y1=$2,y0):(x1-x0):(0):3 w vectors lw 2 lc palette nohead notitle, \
     x1=y1=NaN $Data u (x0=x1,x1=$1,x1):(y0=y1,y1=$2,y0):(0):(y1-y0):3 w vectors lw 2 lc palette nohead notitle
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition:** (vertical lines with variable colors)

Maybe you noticed that with your 4 datapoints there are only 3 colors. This is obvious, because if you have 4 data points you will only have 3 connecting lines, hence 3 colors.

A variation would be the following:
Draw your 4 points with the color according to the value column 3 and the same color for the horizontal lines.
However, for the vertical lines you split the lines into as many levels you want (here: `myLevels = 20`) using the color according to the palette.

**Code:**

```
### plotting with steps and variable line color (vertical lines with variable color)
reset session

$Data <<EOD
1     0.5   0.1
2     0.75  0.2
3     0.99  0.5
4     1.25  1.1
EOD

set xrange [0:5]
set yrange [0:1.5]

myLevels = 20
plot x1=y1=c1=NaN $Data u (x0=x1,x1=$1,x0):(y0=y1,y1=$2,y0):(x1-x0):(0):(c0=c1,c1=$3,c0) w vectors lw 2 lc palette nohead notitle, \
     for [i=0:myLevels-1] x1=y1=NaN $Data u (x0=x1,x1=$1,x1):(y0=y1,y1=$2,y0+(y1-y0)*i/myLevels):(0):((y1-y0)/myLevels):(c0=c1,c1=$3,c0+(c1-c0)*i/myLevels) w vectors lw 2 lc palette nohead notitle, \
     $Data u 1:2:3 w p pt 7 ps 2 lc palette notitle
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: It is not a workaround but rather a better solution for my problem, than steps for it allows to change the color of vertical lines which I need!